# Is it possible to get a reference for binding data in an individual cell for the invocation function in a custom function?

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I need to create multiple custom function that getting data from single webSocket. But, need to required bind message data in all custom function differently.

[image]

See above screenshot I have created two custom function. That running with same webSocket. But, need to bind data in both custom function using invocation. so, can we get reference of both the custom function & can we bind data in that custom function invidually?

[I have followed below steps for implement custom functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/custom-functions-runtime/customfunctions.streaminginvocation?view=excel-js-preview)

Please suggest me any solutions.